# Error when trying to load database into backup server

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase, isql

Im trying to load a database dump into my Sybase backup server.

Running sybase ASE-16_0 on both my primary and backup machine.

Import is done in isql cli via
`load database DB from ./dumps/data_dump`

Error message is the following:

```
Backup Server session id is: 22. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.141.2.40: [11] The 'open' call failed for database/archive
device while working on stripe device
'/opt/dumps/data_dump' with error number
13 (Permission denied). Refer to your operating system documentation for further
details.
```

Also found this SAP Knowledge Base article, but it's hidden behind a paywall:
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/3140989

Comment: seeing how the message mentions `Permission denied` the 1st question would be ... have you confirmed the permissions on the dump file located at `/opt/dumps/data_dump` (eg, can the OS user (`sybase`?) that the `dataserver` and `backupserver` processes running under read the dump file)? 2nd question: is the dump file really located at `/opt/dumps/data_dump`?

Comment: Yes, i manually set permissions so that all users can open the dump file, and the file path is correct too

Comment: when checking permissions did you also check the permissions on the directory? on the same dataserver (where you're having permissions problems) can you dump a small database (eg, model) to the same directory where `data_dump` is located?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a new Server fixed the issue for me. Im still working on a possible answer for this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).